# Grow light recommendations for money-plant on 5ft high trellis in a shaded window

Tags: light, trellis, money-tree-plant

**Context:** My money plant is not growing too well on this trellis. The leaves are yellowing and falling-off too often and the growth is very slow (compared to other money plants which are lying in a balcony which receives good sunlight)

**About the trellis:** The trellis in question is 5 feet high and is installed outside a window which doesn't get much sunlight (mostly reflected sunlight). The picture taken below is at 3pm -- at this time the sun is shining really bright and it's uncomfortable standing out in the open for too long, but this trellis isn't getting much sunlight.

- picture attached below
- here's a 20 second video as well - https://youtube.com/shorts/nPLMDPqUssk?feature=share

**Question:** General recommendation is to have the grow light 2 inches away from the plant? Is this applicable to my case as well? What kind of grow lights would you recommend for my situation?

[image: trellis in shaded window]

Comment: The sunlight may be enough, but the soil could be years old and needs refreshing.